# How to convert string to UTF-8 Decimal in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, decimal-point

How can you convert a string value to decimal code point in xCode? What type of encoding can I use to convert these to the correct representation?

Examples:

string: `9` in decimal code point encoding is `57`

string: `1` in decimal code point encoding is `49`

string: `F` in decimal code point encoding is `70`

Can you give example to how to do this?

Comment: I'd start by figuring out how you convert from one to the other (and back again) on paper.  If you can do it on paper, you can do it on code easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the character value instead of the string value. So instead of string @"F" you want character 'F'. `NSLog(@"F = %d",'F');`

You can do this with a larger string by using the method `characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)` and enumerating over the string.

int encVal = (int)[someString characterAtIndex:0];

Comment: `characterAtIndex:9` just returns `9`, is there no UTF-8 decimal encoding in xCode?

Comment: sorry forgot to say you need to cast said character to int. will edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
unichar ch = [someString characterAtIndex:0]; // assume the 1st character
int code = (int)ch;
```

For the string `@"9"`, `ch` will be the character `'9'` and `code` will be the value `57`.